# Multiline string from oracle to javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle

I have a CLOB column called supplementary with multiline strings, this works fine running within the oracle database but doesn't work on javascript as a result of the multilines, Does anyone know how to make this work with javascript?

```
 SELECT DBMS_LOB.substr((A.SUPPLEMENTARY,3000))  FROM PLACENAMES A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE PLACENAMES
        ("SUPPLEMENTARY" CLOB)
    ;

    INSERT ALL 
        INTO PLACENAMES ("SUPPLEMENTARY")
             VALUES ('Hello Stackoverflow')
    SELECT * FROM dual
    ;

    SELECT DBMS_LOB.substr(A.SUPPLEMENTARY,5)  FROM PLACENAMES A

    |  TEXT |
    |-------|
    | Hello |
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05949/3/0)

equals

```js
var text = "Hello Stackoverflow".substring(0,5);
alert(text);
```

Comment: It should be a multiline string, that's a singe line, I am working it many rows